# Finding 2 middle numbers in a list of 4 numbers in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to write a script that gets 4 numbers and print the 2 middle ones.

I tried something but it does not work well:

```
a = (input('enter first num:'))
b = (input('enter second num:'))
c = (input('enter thirs num:'))
d = (input('enter forth num:'))

##a=float(a)
##b=float(b)    
##c=float(c)
##d=float(d)

List=[a,b,c,d]
L=[]
for i in List:
        if i >> min(List):
            if i << max(List):
              L.append(i)
print L
```

I am not sure what the problem is because the output list is not coherent and actually depends on the input.

I would like to get a clue or idea how to solve this (with using only lists, for and if - this is basic level course for non-programmers)

Comment: `>>` and `<<` are bit-shifting. Use `>` and `<` instead.

Comment: note that `<< != <`. where `<<` is a bitwise operator, `<` is a boolean comparison operator.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham after re-reading the question I believe OP wants the middle 2 numbers based on their value, not the position.

Comment: `set(List) - {min(List), max(List)}`, `sorted(List)[1:-1]`

Comment: @DeepSpace. yes that would make more sense

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus, that wont work if you have repated numbers

Comment: @Amir,  what should `1122` output or `1111`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your if statements are not behaving as you'd expect.

'>>' and '<<' are not comparison operators. They are [bitwise operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

You simply want to use '>' and '<' to compare values.

Answer (score 5):

this should work. It finds the minimum and maximum element in the list and removes them from the list leaving the middle two.

```
a = int(input('enter first num:'))
b = int(input('enter second num:'))
c = int(input('enter thirs num:'))
d = int(input('enter forth num:'))

L = [a, b, c, d]

minimum = a
maximum = d
for i in L:
    if i < minimum:
        minimum = i
    if i > maximum:
        maximum = i
tmp = L[:]
tmp.remove(minimum)
tmp.remove(maximum)
print tmp
```

**Note:** this will only remove the minimum and maximum numbers and will only leave two numbers if the list is of size 4

Here is another way to do it using the sort function which sorts the list in place and then you can just grab the elements by index.

```
a = int(input('enter first num:'))
b = int(input('enter second num:'))
c = int(input('enter thirs num:'))
d = int(input('enter forth num:'))

L=[a,b,c,d]

L.sort()
print L[1]
print L[2]
```

If you want to add them to a list instead you could do

```
new_L = [L[1], L[2]]
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Oh, I just skimmed, I missed that. I'll update.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I updated my answer although I'm not sure what OP expected for inputs like `1 1 1 2` since there's technically no middle numbers. I just made it match the sort methods answer

Comment: `del tmp.remove(minimum)` is not valid syntax, if you want to not change the original list you also need to copy `L`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks for catching that. I had `del tmp[tmp.index()]` and changed it to `remove`

Answer (score 0):

First prompt for all the numbers, convert each to an integer, sort them and then select the middle two as follows:

```
middle = sorted(int(input('enter {} num: '.format(p))) for p in ['first', 'second', 'third', 'forth'])[1:-1]
print 'The middle numbers are:', middle
```

So for example you would see the following:

```
enter first num: 10
enter second num: 3
enter third num: 8
enter forth num: 5
The middle numbers are: [5, 8]
```

Comment: guys, thank you very much, for all of you.
i did this newbie mistake, using ">>" insted of ">".